# Why package-private classes are not accessible from nested packages?

Tags: java, project, package-private

I was planning a testing strategy for one of the projects I'm working for and my plan was to create some package-private annotations and make them available only down the package structure. For instance:

```
- com.myproject.test.it.BaseIT.class (annotation)
- com.myproject.test.it.foo.FooIT (one test class)

- com.myproject.test.component.BaseComponentTest.class (annotation)
- com.myproject.test.component.bar.BarComponentTest.class (another test class)
```

`BaseIT.class` and `BaseComponentTest.class` are my annotations.
`BaseIT.class` would be available inside `.it` and any other nested packaged like `.it.foo`.

The same would happen with BaseComponentTest.class.

Comment: Nesting doesn't mean anything to the language, they're just different packages. As to why, maybe ask james gosling.

Comment: It's a bit of a flaw in the language imo.  Java package names are not hierarchical or "nested," they're just different package names.  There's no way to specify a "friend" class or package (like C++), so the only way to allow access outside of a package it to allow it for everyone.  I think recent iterations of Java allow for "sealed" packages and "unsealed" specific classes, that might help, but if you need to support versions of Java prior to (I think) Java 14 you'll be out of luck.

Comment: Java sealed classes: https://www.baeldung.com/java-sealed-classes-interfaces

Comment: Java sealed classes on StackOverflow (and it's Java 17, so later than I thought): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218585/what-are-sealed-classes-in-java-17